# Code coverage will not be imported for the following file outside of SonarQube

Tags: c#, sonarqube, sonar-runner

i'm running SonarQube 5.2, Sonar runner 2.4, with OpenCover for code coverage. When running the Sonar for a project with OpenCover xml i'm getting the error below. The analyze is done in D:\sTFS\28983\Sources\ApplicationsLauncher\Source, and the coverage xml in D:\sTFS\28983\Sources\ApplicationsLauncher\Source\opencover1.xml. ApplicationsLauncher.UnitTests.cs file is not a shared one. Any idea why the code coverage isn't shown?

16:40:03.802 INFO  - Parsing the OpenCover report D:\sTFS\28983\Sources\ApplicationsLauncher\Source\opencover1.xml
16:40:03.802 DEBUG - Code coverage will not be imported for the following file outside of SonarQube: D:\sTFS\28983\Sources\ApplicationsLauncher\Source\ApplicationsLauncher.UnitTests\ApplicationsLauncher.UnitTests.cs

Comment: so what is the question ?

Comment: I edited the post so it will be clear

Comment: Still having this problem also on another project. Any idea why?